# Find the formula using the combination method

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, combinations

How do I use the combination method to derive the formulas for the sequence:

```
3, 3, 9, 27, 63, 123...
```

I was able to find the explicit formula for this sequence using a difference table. In closed form/explicit form the solution is:

```
An = 2n^3 - 2n + 6 / 2
```

My instructor hasn't used the wordage "combination method", in class prior to this question, and I don't know how to solve it using the combination method. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That last sentence is very poorly phrased and extremely unclear. What exactly is the question???

Answer (score 1):

This is the Combination Method.

Lets Assume an Equation of 3<sup>rd</sup> degree
$ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = e$
where $e$ is the value of each number in sequence
so the sequence 3 ,3 , 9 , 27 , 63 , 123

- $a1^3 + b1^2 + c1 + d = 3$
- $a2^3 + b2^2 + c2 + d = 3$
- $a3^3 + b3^2 + c3 +    d = 9$
- $a4^3 + b4^2 + c4 + d = 27$
- $a5^3 + b5^2 + c5 + d = 63$

and solving them